# Does Identity Model have token auto-refresh for the password resource owner flow?

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

When using the `RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync`extenstion for a `TokenClient`, given a response with a `refresh_token` and `expires_in` is there a default in-memory impementation of a token cache?

Which, upon `access_token` expiry (auto-evicted from cache) the token client can use to request a token using the refresh token.

Or do we have to rollout our own?

```
private async Task<string> GetToken(
    string clientId, string clientSecret, string username, string password)
{
    string tokenAddress = "https://api.example.com/oauth2/token";
    var tokenClient = new TokenClient(tokenAddress, clientId, clientSecret);
    var result = await tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync(username, password);

    // do we create a wrapper around the token client that will implement a cache and auto-refresh
    // so that the next call, with same arguments will return same result.AccessToken
    // if still within bounds of the TimeNow.AddSeconds(result.ExpiresIn) window

    return result.AccessToken;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't tag with identity-model :-/

Comment: Doesn't have to be the password resource owner flow I guess.. can be applicable to any flow that appreciates a token cache.

Comment: With a refresh token you can use https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2/blob/release/src/IdentityModel/Client/RefreshTokenDelegatingHandler.cs